# Camera option disappears in phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a HTML5 web app that works perfectly in a browser on a phone.

To select an image I offer a choice of camera or anything else basically (gallery etc)

```
<!--- select device camera -->
<input type="file" id="takePictureFieldCam" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

<!-- select anything from device... camera, gallery etc -->
<input type="file" id="takePictureFieldGal" accept="image/*">
```

When I bundle this into a phonegap app there is no camera option any more. Both choices result in a user choice of everything (e.g. gallery) but not the camera.

Is this a known bug?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: this happens on android, right? it's not really a bug, but it's how it works on phonegap apps

Comment: is there a workaround for it? yeah it's android

Comment: no workaround, sorry. You can show a prompt (from dialogs plugin) to choose camera or gallery and then use the camera plugin with sourceType Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, but that won't be a form element, so will have to use file transfer plugin to submit it to your server